# Chrome Extension Package Size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I need to get the size of the extension package. To do that, I have this code:

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(package) {
  package.getMetadata(function(metadata) {
    console.log(metadata.size)
}) })
```

The problem is that it is always 4096. Always. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to enumerate all files in the package and calculate the size, here's an example that works in a background/event page:

```
function calcPackageSize(callback) {
    var totalSize = 0;
    var queue = [], xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function() {
        totalSize += this.response.size;
        calcFile();
    };
    chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {
        var rootDirNameLength = root.fullPath.length;
        calcDir(root);
        function calcDir(dir) {
            dir.createReader().readEntries(function(entries) {
                entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                    if (entry.isFile) {
                        queue.push(entry.fullPath.substr(rootDirNameLength));
                        !xhr.readyState && calcFile(); // start the request chain
                    } else {
                        calcDir(entry);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
    function calcFile() {
        if (!queue.length)
            return callback && callback(totalSize);
        xhr.open("HEAD", queue.pop());
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
calcPackageSize(function(size) { console.log(size) });
```

Comment: No, it crashes the extension.

Comment: @DanielHerr, I can't reproduce neither on Chrome 46 nor on old Chrome 31, [here's a minimal extension](https://puu.sh/k54D3/4962ad74de/calcPackageSize.crx). Save the file and drag it onto an opened chrome://extensions page, then click the extension button, it'll show its size in an alert box.

Comment: Must be only allowed to run in the background page, but that seems rather odd.

Comment: Why odd? I think it's normal and actually expected because some APIs also require that.